# How to use substring() with Import.io?

Tags: xpath, import.io

I'm having some issues with XPath and import.io and I hope you'll be able to help me. :)

The html code:

```
<a href="page.php?var=12345">
```

For the moment, I manage to extract the content of the href ( *page.php?var=12345* ) with this:

```
./td[3]/a[1]/@href
```

Though, I would like to just collect: **12345**

substring might be the solution but it does not seem to work on import.io as I use it...

```
substring(./td[3]/a[1]/@href,13)
```

Any ideas of what the problem is?

Thank's a lot in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using this for the xpath: (Have the field selected as Text)

```
.//*[@class='oeil']/a/@href
```

Then use this for your regex:

```
([^=]*)$
```

This will get you the ISBN number you are looking for.

import.io only support functions in XPath when they return a node list

Comment: Awesome! It works! I just had to add your regex expression to my XPath code and I get the ISBN number! Thanks a lot Wilson! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your path expression is fine, but perhaps it should be

```
substring(./td[3]/a[1]/@href,14)
```

"Does not seem to work" is not a very clear description of what is wrong. Do you get error messages? Is the output wrong? Do you have any code surrounding the path expression you could show?

---

You can use substring, but using `substring-after()` would be even better.

```
substring-after(/a/@href,'=')
```

assuming as input the tiny snippet you have shown:

```
<a href="page.php?var=12345"/>
```

will select

```
12345
```

and taking into account the structure of your input

```
substring-after(./td[3]/a[1]/@href,'=')
```

A leading `.` in a path expression selects only immediate child `td` nodes of the current context node. I trust you know what you are doing.

Comment: Hello Mathias! Thank's for your quick reply. :)

You're right "doesn't seem to work" is -quite- vague... Well, when I put my path expression, the line litterally disappears from the result page... as if the function does not exist.

This is why I'm asking if import.io accepts substring(). 

Yes, I know for the leading ., but be assured that it works fines to get the href content as import.io defines each line as row.

Maybe it will be easier with the page: http://www (dot) edistat (dot) com/palmares.php

Comment: @Pierre I would like to reproduce your problem on import.io. Where can I enter an XPath expression?

Comment: Create an Extractor for the page I gave you (Edistat.com), then add a new column, select a link of a book, and finally, on the top right of the window, clic on the "screw-wrench" (left button close to the CSS button) to access to the advanced settings: the XPath and regex fields should then appear.

Comment: Mathias, thank's for your kind help. Wilson has just found the solution. It seems indeed that import.io does not support functions in XPath. :)

Comment: @Pierre That's fine - I'm glad someone found a solution. And good to know that import.io has the most incomplete implementation of XPath I have ever seen...