# XPath - Extract spectific file name from string

Tags: xpath, import.io

I'm trying to extract just the filename from a javascript link in import.io, eg `googlebolver.htm` from `href="javascript:finpopup('googlebolver.htm',920,620,0)"`

I've managed to get to the  'link' (`javascript:finpopup('googlebolver.htm',920,620,0)`) with the following XPath

```
//*[text()='GOOGLE.MAPS']/@href
```

but I would like to get to the actual address on its own. 
As I am running the import.io Extracto on multiple urls, I want it to find something like `*.htm`

I believe this maybe possible by using the substring function, but I don't know how to do it.
The following questions of this site looked promising, but one only works for fixed length stings and the other I don't completely understand and works for only a specific 'word'

1. [Extract value from javascript object in site using xpath and import.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402951/extract-value-from-javascript-object-in-site-using-xpath-and-import-io)
2. [How to use substring() with Import.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636372/how-to-use-substring-with-import-io)

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT: Here is the [URL](http://www.vieferrate.it/pag-relazioni/trentino-alto-adige/88-gruppo-pale-san-martino/40-bolver-lugli.html)

Comment: Can you share your URL

Comment: @AndrewFogg Done :-) I'm using a search XPath instead of location because some other pages put it in a different order

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath functions `substring-after` and `substring-before`, to select the text after, say,  `('` and before `',`

in your example, it would be

```
substring-before(substring-after(//*[text()='GOOGLE.MAPS']/@href,"('"),"',")
```

Note: I don't know if import.io supports these standard XPath function